# ionic-menu track/listen to IsOpen property

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I currently have a ionic-menu which opens/closes based on user interaction.
Now i would like to fire an animation in an unrelated object when the menu opens/closes.
Therefore I would like to listen to Open/Close, hence convert the **this.menu.isOpen** and **this.menu.isAnimating** properties into observables so i could subscribe to it.

How would one do this?

Comment: I figured it out, theres another property "this.menu.ionOpen" or "this.menu.ionClose", i'm able to subscribe to.